# Creating 3D Models from 2D arrays

Tags: model, 3d, file-type, mayavi

I am currently using mayavi to do some work with 3D models. The coordinates for my points are divided into 3 different 2d arrays, namely, x, y, and z. Having it set up like this makes it easy for me to use a function such as mesh, and apply color to each individual point on my model.

I am interested in producing a new model though using a program such as blender, or sketch app. These programs are capable of exporting models in a variety of formats, but I'm not aware of any which will provide me with the point coordinates in 3 2d-arrays. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I might be able to go about this?

Comment: blender offers Python 3.x APIs, just start with it and use this kind of scripting solution.

Comment: also most formats are arrays like you requested. For example a obj file flits the bill, its easy enough to understand as its text. However since the points are a actually a graph of some kind the data also needs connectivity info which you can safely ignore.